# В URL Wordpress добавляется какая-то строка (например #.UE2qGaDxR5E)

Tags: url, seo, php, wordpress

Всем добрый день, не могу понять в чём дело, в адресную строку браузера вконец URL адреса добавляются странные строки (например `#.UE2qGaDxR5E` или `#.UCjF0aA2crs`  или `#.UE2v_6DxR5E`), все начинаются на #. а дальше Бог знает что... Самое печально эти ссылки попадают в индекс. Подскажите как отловить ошибку, почему может такое происходить? Никаких редиректов или багов в .htaccess я не обнаружил. Ума не приложу что делать. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Версия Wordpress 3.4.2, на сайте установлен компонент Magic Fields и портативный `phpMyAdmin`.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем всё оказалось неожиданно просто, на сайте разработчики установили сторонний скрипт формирования кнопок социальных сетей (twitter,facebook и  google+), скрипт зарубежный и с очередным обновлением стал добавлять вышеупомянутые "кракозябры" (#.UE2qGaDxR5E) в конец адреса url. Кстати самый простой способ выявить ошибку - это запретить выполнение java script на странице, например с помощью расширения Web Developer для Mozilla. Всем спасибо! =)

Comment: Или отключить `javascript` вообще.

Comment: не ну вообще нельзя, там другие скрипты работают полезные =)